# Howto include output of a script into the zsh prompt

Tags: zsh, python, prompt

I would like to add the output of a Python script into my `zsh` prompt but I am not sure how to do it?

Is this done by what is called "PROMPT EXPANSION" in the man pages?

Please someone set me on the right track, i.e. post some helpful links I could not find with Google.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two principal ways:

1. Parameter expansion by enabling `PROMPT_SUBST`
2. The `psvar` array

#### 1. Parameter expansion in prompt

If `PROMPT_SUBST` is enabled

```
setopt PROMPT_SUBST
```

the prompt is subjected to parameter  expansion, command substitution and arithmetic expansion before it is evaluated.

That way, the output of a script can be included via command substitution. For example:

```
PROMPT='Look at this: $(python yourscript.py) >'
```

If the output contains escape sequences (`%~`, `%M`, `%F{red}` etc.) they will be evaluated before the prompt is printed.

#### 2. The psvar array

One of the first nine values of the array `psvar` can be set to the output of the script. It can then be recalled by using `%Xv`, where `X` is a number between 1 and 9 (defaults to 1 if `X` is left out).

```
psvar[5]=$(python yourscript.py)
PROMPT='Look at this: %5v >'
```

In order to refresh the value every time before the prompt is printed, the hook function `precmd` has to be set:

```
precmd() {
    psvar[5]=$(python yourscript.py)
}
```

If there already is a `precmd` function, or if more than one function is to be used, it is a good idea to use `add-zsh-hook`.

```
# load add-zsh-hook, need to be done only once
autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook

pyscript() {
    psvar[5]=$(python yourscript.py)
}

add-zsh-hook precmd pyscript
```

This adds `pycript` to the list of functions that need to be run before printing the prompt.

Comment: though using the solution with psvar the return string itself is not not evaluuated as you showed in solution 1. Is there a possibility to do this also in solution 2?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by setting up a `precmd` hook which will take the output of the command and format it as you want, and then make it available to your PROMPT. Minimally, you need:

```
autoload -U add-zsh-hook
add-zsh-hook precmd my_precmd_hook_function
```

Define `my_precmd_hook_function` to call your python script and capture its output in a variable. You can then use that variable in your $PROMPT:

```
my_precmd_hook_function() {
  python_says=$(myPythonScript arg1 arg2)
}

PROMPT='$python_says'
```

You can set as many variables as you need in your `precmd` hook and use them to build a quite complex PROMPT. Just bear in mind that the more you do in the `precmd` hook, the longer it will take `zsh` to draw the prompt and return control to you. If your python script is more than trivially simple, you will undoubtedly notice a lag.

You can see the full range of possibilities in the `SIMPLE PROMPT ESCAPES` section of the `zshmisc` man page.

Comment: Note that the shell option `PROMPT_SUBST` needs to be enabled in order to expand parameters in the prompt string.