# How do I include the current Anaconda env in my prompt?

Tags: terminal, zsh, python, prompt

I found [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/472878/how-do-i-modify-my-conda-env-variable-in-my-terminal-prompt) that perfectly describes the problem I'm having. The only difference is that I'm using zsh. When I escape the '$' as @filbranden described, it just prints the `$(basename $CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV)` to the prompt. The following sort of works, but doesn't update with activation as @johnchase described originally.

```
PS1=$'\n'"%F{blue}[ %F{green}%n%F{white}@%F{yellow}%m%F{white}:%F{cyan}%d %F{blue}]"$'\n'
PS1+="%F{cyan}("$(basename $CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV)") %F{white}:> "
```

Gives me:

```
(base) :> conda activate datasci

[ downtime@samurai:/home/downtime ]
(base) :>                                                                                                                                                                         [insert]

[ downtime@samurai:/home/downtime ]
(base) :> echo $CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV                                                                                                                                                 [insert]
datasci
```

And if I change to :

```
PS1=$'\n'"%F{blue}[ %F{green}%n%F{white}@%F{yellow}%m%F{white}:%F{cyan}%d %F{blue}]"$'\n'
PS1+="%F{cyan}(\$(basename \$CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV)) %F{white}:> "
```

I get:

```
[ downtime@samurai:/home/downtime ]
($(basename $CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV)) :>
```

Does zsh handle PS1 so differently? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Per usual, I discovered the answer within minutes of posting my question, even though I've already spent hours trying to figure it out. The answer is, yes, zsh is apparently quite different. [This post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157693/howto-include-output-of-a-script-into-the-zsh-prompt) is what led me to the answer.

```
precmd() {
       psvar[1]=$CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV:t
}
PS1=$'\n'"%F{blue}[ %F{green}%n%F{white}@%F{yellow}%m%F{white}:%F{cyan}%d %F{blue}]"$'\n'
PS1+="%F{cyan}(%1v) %F{white}:> "
```

See also the `$CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV:t` (from csh) which expands to the `t`ail of the path stored in `$CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV` and is a more efficient and more reliable way than having to spawn a new process that executes an external `basename` utility and read its output through a pipe like `$(basename $CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV)` (which should have been `"$(basename -- "$CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV")"`) does.

Comment: You can also do `set -o promptsubst` for the parameter expansions and command substitutions to be performed upon prompt expansion like in `ksh` / `bash`, but using `$psvar` instead is generally safer and more reliable. See [my recent answer to similar question here](/a/689527)